# Getting Validation Summary RadDataForm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, telerik

we are using Telerik RadDataForm in Our product which is using MVVM Pattern. we want to use our custom Commads  and Button for Commit and Cancel and to get this we are referencing RadDataFormStyle to set the command as shown.

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="PART_FooterPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                  <telerik:RadButton x:Name="PART_CommitButton" Content="{TemplateBinding CommitButtonContent}" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}, Path=Data.UpdateItem}"  InnerCornerRadius="0" Margin="2,4,4,4" MinWidth="48" MinHeight="20">
                                      <telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
                                          <telerik:Office_BlackTheme/>
                                      </telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
                                  </telerik:RadButton>
                                  <telerik:RadButton x:Name="PART_CancelButton" Content="{TemplateBinding CancelButtonContent}" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy},Path=Data.CancelItemUpdate}" InnerCornerRadius="0" Margin="2,4,4,4" MinWidth="48" MinHeight="20">
                                      <telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
                                          <telerik:Office_BlackTheme/>
                                      </telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
                                  </telerik:RadButton>
                              </StackPanel>
```

and following is the Rad Form Defined on the View. the CommandButtonsVisibility="None" is set to None because we don't want to see the navigation and other controls being used.

```
 <telerik:RadDataForm x:Name="DataForm1"                                     CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentLevelItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                     Style="{StaticResource RadDataFormStyle1}"                                      DataFieldStyle="{StaticResource DataFormDataFieldStyle1}" AutoEdit="True" CommandButtonsVisibility="None"  />
```

The fields are auto generated and the problem is we want to get hold of the ValidationString (if the condition of a text field etc is not met the AutoGenerated validation message is Bound to a property in the view Model etc)to show it according to our requirements(i.e. on a one of our custom tool to show information or errors etc) .
is there a way to get hold of the validation string?.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

one way to get hold of Validation Summary object is to bind the Invoke Action to an event as follow and send the Validation Summary as a Command Parameter to the View Model.

```
<telerik:RadDataForm x:Name="DataForm1"
                                     CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentLevelItem,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                     Style="{StaticResource RadDataFormStyle1}"
                                      DataFieldStyle="{StaticResource DataFormDataFieldStyle1}" AutoEdit="True"  CommandButtonsVisibility="None"

                                    ValidationSummaryVisibility="Collapsed"  >                       
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
                                <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ValidationSummaryCmd}" CommandParameter="{Binding ValidationSummary.Errors, ElementName=DataForm1}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </telerik:RadDataForm>
```